# Return Index Position from file content

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I am trying to return index position from WAV files.

If the needle content found in a haystack then I need to return the index position of the needle in the haystack.

```
haystack = open("haystack.wav",'r').read()
needle = open("needle.wav",'r').read()

print(haystack.index(needle[:46]));
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    haystack = open("haystack.wav",'r').read()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
```

It works when I do this in PHP:

```
$needle = file_get_contents("needle.wav", false, null, 46);
$haystack = file_get_contents("haystack.wav");
echo strpos($haystack,$needle);
```

Comment: You're reading the file as text. You should read it as bytes with the `rb` mode. (But then `index` won't work as expected.)

Comment: So what is the solution like I did in PHP? and it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the files as *binary* using `'rb'` under Python 3 you will get `bytes` objects back. Then you can use `.index`:

```
haystack = open("haystack.wav", 'rb').read()
needle = open("needle.wav", 'rb').read()

print(haystack.index(needle[:46]))
```

Example:

```
>>> b'hello world'.index(b'world')
6
>>> b'hello world'.index(b'goodbye')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: Thanks, it appear to be working on Python 2... so it a bug on Python 3?

Comment: Works fine in my Python 3.2, and Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of a mess due to the way python interchanges bytes with ints depending on how they are accessed in objects.  [Here is a bit about that](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2010-May/099292.html).  I tested this by writing an mp3 file twice to a new file.  One observation is that if there is metadata in your needle it will need to be stripped before comparing to a longer file.  In my case, needle had 'encoded with lame #...' in it.  If you were to match this whole mp3 to a longer one there would not be a match.

```
def findneedle(bin1, bin2):
  with open(bin2,'rb') as haystack:
    with open(bin1,'rb') as needle:
      n = needle.read()
      h = []
      EOF = None
      while EOF != b'':
        EOF = haystack.read(1000)
        h.append(EOF)
        if (n in b''.join(h)):
          h = h[:-1]
          haystack.seek(haystack.tell() - 1000)
          while EOF != b'':
            EOF = haystack.read(1)
            h.append(EOF)
            if (n in b''.join(h)):
              return haystack.tell() - len(n)

index = findneedle('a.mp3','b.mp3')
```

Comment: Trying to use a deque really threw me off here.  nneonneo's approach is really quite useful.  I'll leave mine here for a contrast to a quick and simple approach.

Answer (score -1):

`haystack = open("haystack.wav",'rb').read()` would suffice. However, I never tried reading .wav files in php so I don't know whether python and php have same binary encoding structure.

```
>>> a = open("A24.wav", "rb").read()
>>> a[:100]
'RIFF\xf4\xe9\x01\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00D\xac\x00\x00\x88X\x01\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00data\xd0\xe9\x01\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x04\x00\xfc\xff\x04\x00\xfc\xff\x02\x00\x00\x00\xfe\xff\x04\x00\xfb\xff\x05\x00\xfc\xff\x02\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x04\x00'
>>>
```

and you want to find index of string in 'haystack' that matches string from 'needle', you can use regex to do it :

```
import re

haystack = open("haystack.wav", "rb").read()
needle = open("needle.wav", "rb").read()

regex = re.compile(needle[:46])
match = regex.search(haystack)

if match:
    print match.start()
```